# Is it possible to add parts of a file to Git index using libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am using libgit2, actually libgit2sharp, is there a way to add parts of a file similar to what `add -p` in CLI?

I don't find anything from the documentation: http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neither implemented (yet) in `libgit2`, nor in `LibGit2Sharp`.

In order to make this happen sooner rather than later, I'd suggest you to open a feature request in the `libgit2` **[tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/new)**.