# How to partially stage a file with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, .net, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have this file committed:

**foo.txt**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Now I modify it to become:

```
line 1
line 1.5
line 2
line 2.5
line 3
```

and I run `git add . && git diff --cached foo.txt` and this is what I get:

```
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index c4dfc64..4942553 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
 line 1
+line 1.5^M
 line 2
+line 2.5^M
 line 3
```

Let's say I now want to remove `line 1.5` from the index and keep `line 2.5`, how would I do this with LibGit2Sharp?

This can be also asked the other way around: how do I add parts of the file to index? I'm looking for some kind of programmatic version of `git add -p`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add parts of a file to Git index using libgit2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597663/is-it-possible-to-add-parts-of-a-file-to-git-index-using-libgit2)

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously no easy (understand : LibGit2Sharp-native) way to do this.

But it may be possible. Why do you want to remove this particular line ? It depends on your criteria, but the simpler way is to simply edit the file itself (helped by the result of `git diff --cached foo.txt`). So git will not stage your unwanted modifications.